# How to fix owl carouse ipad bug

Tags: ios, ipad, css-transforms, owl-carousel

I think the problem is transform property. Caniuse says safari on IOS have partial support, only with vendor prefix -webkit-, but in ows script i see a code for adding vendor prefixes, so i can't get the problem with this carousel.

initializing plugin code:

```
$(".owl-carousel-beer").owlCarousel({
        items: 2,
        nav: true,
        center: true,
        loop: true,
        dots: false,
        mouseDrag: true,
        stagePadding: 50,
        responsiveClass:true,
        responsive:{
            0:{
                items:1,
                stagePadding: 0,
            },
            480:{
                items:1,
                stagePadding: 0,
            },
            768:{
                items:2,
            },
            1024:{
                items:2,
            },
            1380:{
                items:3,
            },
            1580:{
                items:4,
            }
        }
    });
```

On ipad owl carousel looks like this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6yET.jpg

On android it looks like this perfect carousel

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvwdF.png

Answer (score 0):

Bug was fixed by putting initialization code into script in the html page.